# Python - Sql query to excel is showing as a single column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-excel

I'm exporting a SQL query result to excel in Python. I'm using pyodbc connection for establishing database connection.

```
cursor = db_connect.cursor()
   Expirydate =  date.today() + timedelta(days=90)
   print(Expirydate)
   sql_query = cursor.execute("""Select StaffDetails.TypeOfEmployee, 
   StaffDetails.EmploymentType, StaffDetails.EmploymentCategory, 
   StaffDetails.PreferredEmpFname, StaffDetails.PreferredEmpLname, 
   StaffDetails.Location, StaffDetails.Department, StaffDetails.Section, 
   StaffDetails.JobTitle, StaffDetails.ContractorAgencyName, 
   StaffDetails.SupervisorName, StaffDetails.SupervisorEmail, 
   StaffBiodata.WorkpassType, StaffBiodata.WorkpassExpiryDate 
   from StaffDetails INNER JOIN StaffBiodata ON 
   StaffDetails.StaffID =StaffBiodata.StaffID 
   WHERE Department = 'Operations' AND WorkpassExpiryDate < '%s'""" % Expirydate)
   allrows = sql_query.fetchall()
   for row in allrows:
      print(f'row = {row}')
      print()
   totalrows = len(allrows)
   print("Total Rows : %d" % totalrows)
```

I'm able to export the query result to dataframe and then to excel, the issue I'm facing is the exported excel is displaying the result as a comma separated string in one column.
What I need is a proper excel worksheet with columns with headers,

```
if totalrows > 0:
       try:
           df = pd.DataFrame(allrows)
           
           print(df)
           with pd.ExcelWriter(r'C:\Users\CSV\Staffdata.xlsx') as writer:
               df.to_excel(writer,
                           sheet_name='WorkPassExpiryReport',
                           header=True,index=False)
           
           
       except Exception as e:
           print("Could not write to Excel")
           print(f"Error: {str(e)}")
```

and the date is not showing correctly
[image]

Comment: Because you haven't unpacked `allrows` to separate columns. It's not possible to answer because you haven't actually shown the SQL part of your code

Comment: @roganjosh, i have edited my question with sql query block. Thanks

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame(allrows, columns=[item[0] for item in cursor.description])`

Comment: @roganjosh, i tried this previously, then the try block is not executing.

Comment: @roganjosh, this is the error im getting ------    Error: Shape of passed values is (2, 1), indices imply (2, 14)

Comment: @Teena I have updated your question (moved SQL to the top, converted it to a multi-line string, wrapped one line in the second code block), hoping that my changes better express your intentions.

Answer (score 1):

I manage to fix the issue. Here is the change i have done.

```
       col_headers = [ i[0] for i in cursor.description ]           
       rows = [ list(i) for i in allrows]           
       df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=col_headers)
```

Now data is available in excel file as expected